# Navigation.PopModalAsync() in ViewModel ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, navigation, outofrangeexception

I am trying to display a birthday message to the user on their birthday. I open the page right after they log in using this.

```
protected override async void OnDisappearing()
{
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new BirthdayPage(Navigation));
}
```

Then, in the BirthdayPageViewModel, I am trying to set a command to Navigation.PopModalAsync() so that it will close the page when the close button is clicked.

```
CloseBirthdayPageCommand = new Command(async () => await navigation.PopModalAsync());
```

For some reason, when I do this, it throws an ArgumentOutOfRangeException instead of closing my BirthdayPage.

I find this odd, because I can change the OnDisappearing method to this and it will close it just fine.

```
protected override async void OnDisappearing()
{
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new BirthdayPage(Navigation));
    await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
}
```

Of course this works, but I want the user to be able to close the page by clicking a button. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you call the modal page? add that code as well, please!

Comment: @G.hakim It's already in my post. "await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new BirthdayPage(Navigation));"

Comment: Okay show me the stacktrace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to get this working by switching my BirthdayPageViewModel command line to this

```
CloseBirthdayPageCommand = new Command(async () => await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync());
```